# How to detect if an element exists in Watir

Tags: ruby, watir

I'm relatively new to Watir but can find no good documentation (examples) regarding how to check if an element exists.  There are the API specs, of course, but these make precious little sense to me if I don't find an example.

I've tried both combinations but nothing seems to work...
if browser.image (:src "/media/images/icons/reviewertools/editreview.jpg").exists
then...
if browser.image (:src "/media/images/icons/reviewertools/editreview.jpg").exists?
then...

If anyone has a concrete suggestion as per how to implement this, please help!  Thanks!

Comment: please provide HTML of the image

Comment: Please provide HTML  without it we can only guess at what you are doing wrong, for all we know this thing is not an <img> but perhaps an <input type="button> or a link

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5359556/unable-to-find-method-for-detecting-if-element-exists-on-a-page/5396645#5396645

Answer (score 20):

It seems you are missing a comma between parameters.

Should be

```
if browser.image(:src, "/media/images/icons/reviewertools/editreview.jpg").exists?
```

Also you can find [this page](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/HTML+Elements+Supported+by+Watir) useful in future to know what attributes are supported.

Answer (score 3):

<strike>The code you posted should work just fine.</strike>
Edit: Oops, wrong. As Katmoon pointed out, there is a missing comma.

```
browser.image(:src "/media/images/icons/reviewertools/editreview.jpg").exists?
```

One problem you may get caught up in is if the browser variable you specified is actually an element that doesn't exist.

e.g.

```
b = Watir::IE.start(ipAddress)
b.frame(:name, "doesntExist).image(:src "/media/images/icons/reviewertools/editreview.jpg").exists?
```

The above code will throw a Watir::UnknownFrameException. You can get around this by first verifying the frame exists or by surrounding the code in a begin/rescue block.

Comment: That's still presuming that the thing really is an image..   what if it's a button or a link?  without him providing HTML we can only make guesses.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you are using it correctly. Here is an old [RDoc of Watir](http://wtr.rubyforge.org/rdoc/1.6.5/).

Does it not work because Watir cannot find it? Hard to tell because there is no source or link to the page that is being tested. I think that I only use **image.exists?**. In general, errors that come from when the image exists but is not found are:

1. The how is not compatible with the element type. There is a cheatsheet to help you see which object types can be found with different attributes [here](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/HTML+Elements+Supported+by+Watir).
2. The what is not correct. You may have to play with that a little bit. Consider trying a regex string to match it such as browser.image(:src, /editreview.jpg/). As a last resort, maybe use element_by_xpath, but there are maintenance costs with that.
3. The location is not correct. Maybe the element is in a frame or something like that. browser.frame("detail").image(:src, /editreview.jpg/).

Try those, but please let me know what worked. One more thing, what are you checking for? If it's part of the test criteria, you can handle it that way. If you need to click on it, then forget the .exists? and just click on it. Ruby will let you know if it's not there. If you need it to be grace, learn about [begin/rescue](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_exceptions.htm).

Good luck,

Dave

Comment: Thank you guys for your answer.   Dave, can you please specify an example of how I am supposed to use image.exists?  The code I am using is:

if browser.image (:src "/media/images/icons/reviewertools/editreview.jpg").exists?

Doesn't work and returns:

Admin_Panel2.rb:45: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting kEND
...reviewertools/editreview.jpg").exists?
                              ^
Admin_Panel2.rb:48: syntax error, unexpected kELSE, expecting kEND
Admin_Panel2.rb:212: syntax error, unexpected kEND, expecting $end

Sorry, but I am lost without a specific example.  Thanks.

Comment: @rijksband A syntax error means that the ruby interpreter had a problem parsing the code. It could mean a missing/extra parentheses or  comma or a lot of other reasons. In this case it is most likely the missing comma between :src and the image path. You might want to consider using a more powerful editor because many of them will point out the error to you as it is written.