# Unable to find method for detecting if element exists on a page

Tags: ruby, watir

I'm very new to Watir.

I have a bit of Ruby/Watir code that is supposed to detect if an element, exists, and if so, click it, if not, click a different element.  Both elements, show up, every time.  Unfortunately nothing I've tried works.

```
if browser.contains_text("/media/images/icons/reviewertools/editreview.jpg")
then browser.image(:src => "/media/images/icons/reviewertools/editreview.jpg").click
else browser.image(:src => "/media/images/icons/reviewertools/savereview.jpg").click
end
```

This eventually fails with "Unable to locate element, using {:src=>"/media/images/icons/reviewertools/savereview.jpg"} (Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException)"

It should have clicked /editreview.jpg, which was visible.

I have also tried:

```
if browser.image("/media/images/icons/reviewertools/savereview.jpg").exists
then browser.image(:src => "/media/images/icons/reviewertools/savereview.jpg").click
```

as well as:

```
if browser.image("/media/images/icons/reviewertools/savereview.jpg").exists?
```

Note that NONE of these cases detect the element, or failing to do that, execute the else clause.

Please, if you respond, provide specific code examples for your suggestions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect if an element exists in Watir](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5358518/how-to-detect-if-an-element-exists-in-watir)

Comment: For the things you have tried, but did not work, what happened?  did you get an error message, and if so what was it?   When you ask questions, it helps to provide specific information, not just 'didn't work' HOW didn't it work is usually valuable info,

Comment: Also, if you want us to provide you with specific code examples, then please provide us with specific HTML examples.   We cannot provide code samples other than a guess unless we see the HTML.   If you want people to write your code for you, the least you can do is provide them the HTML they are coding against..  Otherwise expect at best guesses or general advice.  (it's nobody here's job to write your code for you)

Answer (score 2):

1. There are only methods "exist?" and "exists?". So "exist" won't work. Consult [here](http://wtr.rubyforge.org/rdoc/1.6.5/).
2. Can you try to identify existence of a different element, such as a link. Does it work for you? There shouldn be no exception. Watir needs to return False in this case.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the same syntax with both the click and the exists? methods. This has also been pointed out by Kat and Chuck and Kinofrost.

```
if browser.image(:src => "/media/images/icons/reviewertools/editreview.jpg").exists?
then browser.image(:src => "/media/images/icons/reviewertools/editreview.jpg").click
else browser.image(:src => "/media/images/icons/reviewertools/savereview.jpg").click
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend checking the DOM to double check the src for your image matches what you're putting. Press F12 in IE8, or use whatever tool is relevant to your browser. You could try using IRB to connect to the browser and try and find the image.

If these fail then I'd try locating the image another way. If the image is in a form this can cause problems and you'll have to locate the form before the image.

Or try another way to locate it, just to make sure that it's possible.

```
browser.image(:index => 3).click
browser.image(:id => 'an_image').click
browser.div(:id => 'image_container').image(:index => 2).click
```

You can use [this link](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/HTML+Elements+Supported+by+Watir) to see what ways you can identify an image, and don't forget that you can use more than one identifier at a time, eg. (:class => /regexofaclass/, :index => 2)

There's nothing wrong with your code as it is (apart from the ? at the end of "exists", and the last line which doesn't contain what you're looking for).

Answer (score 1):

Presuming that this thing really is an 'image' as defined by it's HTML tag, your attempt to identify if the object is there is failing because

1. you are not using the right method, in Ruby, methods that return a bool end in a question mark
2. it's not text,

and in the other attempt you provided only a 'what' and not a how, and still used the wrong method.

try this

```
if browser.image(:src, "/media/images/icons/reviewertools/savereview.jpg").exists?
then browser.image(:src, "/media/images/icons/reviewertools/savereview.jpg").click
```

Otherwise have a good look at the HTML, are you actually looking at a 'button' perhaps?